# How to install setup tools on Python 2.7?

Tags: python, setuptools

When I try

```
/bin/sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

it says python 2.7 not found, my python is in

```
/opt/python27/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a `PATH=$PATH:/opt/python27/bin`

and then try and run the setup again.

You need python in your path.

make sure `which python` pounts to the one in `/opt/python27/bin`.